# Solutions with incredibly long computing times

Tags: discussion

In [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), are solutions allowed that have an incredibly long, but provably finite computation time?

Of course assuming the question does not specifically rule those out.

Comment: I haven't seen anything to suggest they *shouldn't* be allowed by default, but maybe my search skill is lacking today.

Comment: @PeterTaylor There doesn't seem to be concensus on the answers on that question.

Comment: The answers are not identical, but they're all agreeing that in general code golf questions do not by default have time limits. The consensus seems pretty clear to me. Besides, the issue of whether or not the previous question has a clear consensus is independent of the issue of whether or not this question is a duplicate of it.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I agree with the fact that the question is a duplicate, I do not agree with the concensus. There are multiple answers disagreeing, and the most upvoted answer is incredibly vague and not really an answer. (We really can not allow "it's subjective" in deciding what kind of answers are allowed or not for a property as basic as runtime.)

Comment: The "it's subjective" part of that answer isn't about whether the answer is allowed or not but whether to upvote it or not. If you want a clearer consensus you can bump the question by posting a clearer answer (or maybe a bounty for a clearer answer), and then ask people on chat for dissent.

Answer (score 7):

## Yes, by default

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) submissions should be allowed to take as much (finite) time as necessary by default. The OP may override this if they wish, e.g. by specifying a time limit or requiring that submissions have to terminate at least once for given test cases.

Because proving program correctness is tricky business, the poster is recommended to explain their code and provide some smaller test cases for which the program *is* testable.

Comment: The answerer might say what they think their code does, but that doesn't prove 1) that it does what they say it does 2) that it acts correctly according to the challenge. How is an answer to be judged, when running its TIO interface runs out of time, even on test cases for testing correctness?